# A function to detect if mouse moved in 5 seconds

Tags: c, windows

I want to detect if mouse moved in 5 seconds, if yes time elapsed is showed. Here is my code, it seems ok but doesn't work correctly.

```
void timer()
{
    if (ismouseclick(WM_MOUSEMOVE))
    {
        movetime=clock();
        clearmouseclick(WM_MOUSEMOVE);
    }
    if ((clock()-movetime)<6)
    {
        sprintf(time_str,"%d",clock();
        outtextxy(275,483,"Time: ");
        outtextxy(340,483,time_str);
    }
    else
    {
        setfillstyle(1,0);
        bar(275,483,370,500);
    }
}
```

Comment: What operating system, libraries etc are you using? Show the complete source file with `#includes`.

Comment: C does not have built-in support for working with peripherals such as a mouse. You must specify which environment you are doing this in. The `WM_` constants seem like Win32, but why make us guess?

Comment: and what does 'doesn't work correctly' mean?

Comment: I use winbgi library, function gives very big numbers.

Comment: does 'clock()' return seconds?

Comment: I think it should be... ((clock()-movetime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC <6)... maybe

Comment: Where do you actually create a timer? You should be watching for `WM_TIMER` messages, too. And what is the `ismouseclick` function? This code doesn't make any sense, not surprising that it doesn't work. Hard to tell you how to fix it unless we're allowed to see the *rest* of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about clock() function. You need to divide it to CLK_TCK (a constant) if you want seconds.

```
(clock()/CLK_TCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` typically returns the elapsed time in milliseconds (this is OS dependent, so check your OS's documentation), so when you are checking whether `(clock() - movetime) < 6`, that's not the elapsed time in actual seconds, but most likely milliseconds.  Therefore you're probably not seeing the print-out you're expecting (i.e., it probably prints ever time you call `timer()`, or maybe it doesn't print at all).